# Full-screen Lightning app launched from Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, mobile

What I am looking to do is build a full-screen app that can be launched from the Salesforce1 navigation menu.

The approach I've taken is to create a Visualforce page that houses the Lightning app, create a Visualforce tab for displaying in the mobile navigation menu, and create a Lightning app that houses the outermost Lightning component of the app.

The problem I'm experiencing is that I need to display this Visualforce page without the standard Salesforce1 header:

[image: Visualforce wrapping Lightning app & Lightning component]

Where I'd ideally just have a full-page, blank slate to create the app out of Lightning components.

Am I approaching this the right way? Can I launch a full page Lightning app (accessible from mobile navigation) in another way? Or can I use the Visualforce route where it's possible to get rid of the Salesforce1 blue bar with the menu hamburger, search icon, and notification symbol?

Comment: The other approach I've found is making the Lightning App a Connected App and simply point the Start URL to the Lightning App URL. In this approach, how would I add the link to the Connected App to Salesforce1 navigation?